# implement own smileys icons for sending and receiving (i have my own designed images ) for iPhone chat application

Tags: ios

how to implement own smileys icons for sending and receiving (i have my own designed images ) in my iPhone  chat application ,I just need process what to follow for that?

Comment: show some programming efforts. Do you want some concept on it to follow OR anything else. Please elobrate

Comment: @ArpitKumar thanks for the reply i really need concept on it

Comment: ok, i have successfully implimented it on my app which is on symbian (j2me). I am sharing it in answer below.have a look on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step implementation of smileys icons for sending in the app.

1. Put all **smileys** icons in your project resources with a specific unique name.
2. Now with pen & paper decide a unique code for every smileys icon. Be careful that code should be such that not used in the chatting generally.
3. When a user select a icon in chat then before sending this message another side scan it & replace it via code(via `identifing it's unique name`).
4. And at the receiver side before showing this message to user repalce code with the image.
5. So there is no need to send `images` over communication , it will increase the load on message size.
6. From user prespective , user will feel like that icons sends over the communication but actually it will be from local resoures.

Hope this helps you. Any thing you want to ask, you are free to ask in comments.